# Сортировка по двум параметрам(Java)

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, cтолкнулся с такой проблемой, что надо отсортировать ArrayList по двум параметрам, по имени владельца и по цене комнаты

На данный момент вот так выглядит класс комната

```
class Room {
String Name;
String Surname;
String RoomS;
int RoomN;
int RoomQ;
float cost;





Room(String Name,String Surname,String RoomS,int RoomN,int RoomQ,float cost) {
    this.Name=Name;
    this.Surname=Surname;
    this.RoomS=RoomS;
    this.RoomN=RoomN;
    this.RoomQ=RoomQ;
    this.cost=cost;

}}
```

Все эти данные считываются из файла. На данный момент у меня получилось лишь сравнить только по цене.А надо чтобы сравнивалось одновременно и по имени владельца, и по цене комнаты.

Так выглядит мой компаратор на данный момент

```
Collections.sort(r, new Comparator<Room>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Room r1, Room r2) {
            int result = (int) (r2.cost - r1.cost);
            if(result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
            return 0;
        }

    });
```

Без понятия, как это сделать.

Добавил потом к классу комнаты

```
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
```

И код, который был предложен ниже заработал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(r, new Comparator<Room>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Room r1, Room r2) {
        int result = (int) (r2.cost - r1.cost);
        if(result != 0) {
            return result;
        }else{
            return r1.getName().compareTo(r2.getName());            
        }
    }

});
```

вам не хватило всего 1 блока `else`. Сначала вы сравниваете цену, если вернулся 0 (цены равны), то возвращаете результат сравнения имен (без разницы какой).

Comment: У меня подчеркивает красным то, что написано в блоке else

Comment: да, ошибся с методом. не compare а compareTo

Comment: я добавил это в класс комнаты   
public String getName() {
  return Name;
 }
Правда мне кажется, что он до сих пор сортирует по ценне

Comment: Если сортировка используется в разных кусках кода и при чем одна и та-же - то лучше `implements Comparable`